# VBA Loop Debugging - Next Without For

Tags: vba, excel

Essentially Im trying to copy and insert a certain range of cells on the second sheet as the program loops through a range of cells on the first sheet as long as the cells arent empty.  I need the copy and insert range to change to the newly copy and inserted cells for each loop.  Any help would be much appreciated

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    For i = 12 To 24
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input")
        With ws
            If Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 2)) Then
            For j = 10 To -2
                Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Budget Output #2")
                With ws
                    Set rng = .Range("Cell(5,i-j):Cell(17,i-j+1)")
                    rng.Copy
                    rng.Offset(0, 2).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
                    rng.Offset(0, 2).ColumnWidth = 20
                    Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Next j
    Next i
            End If
                End With
        End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Using proper indentation might show you where you are going wrong.  Anytime you have an `End` something, you should indent the code between the Start and End so you notice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need the `With` statements for ONE line.  This will be much cleaner.  Also with two sheets, you should use TWO sheet variables.  Finally, I cleaned up your `Range(Cells, Cells)` syntax.  Although, this will still not work because of your `For j = 10 to -2`.  To move backwards, you have to use a `Step -#`.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim wsIn As Worksheet, wsOut As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    Set wsIn = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input")
    Set wsOut = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Budget Output #2")    

    x = 2
    For i = 12 To 24
        If Not IsEmpty(wsIn.Cells(i, 2)) Then
            Set rng = wsOut.Range("B:C")
            rng.Copy
            rng.Offset(0, x).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
            rng.Offset(0, x).ColumnWidth = 20
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            x = x + 2
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Like this?For j = 10 To -2 Step -1
     Set rng = wsOut.Range(Cells(5, i - j), Cells(17, i - j + 1))

Comment: Hmm, debugger is highlighting "Set rng = wsOut.Range(Cells(5, i - j), Cells(17, i - j + 1))" with an error "method 'range of object' worksheet failed... any ideas?  Sorry if this request is above and beyond

Comment: That `i-j` stuff is tricky given you `i` changes so much.  What are you actually trying to do with each iteration of `i`?

Comment: basically cells 12 through 24 will either have an employees name in it or not.  for each iteration, if there is an employee in cell 12-24 on the first worksheet, goes through that list and will copy and insert two columns on the second worksheet after the most recently inserted columns.

Comment: Where do the columns need to be added?  Your j loop isn't making much sense right now.

Comment: if theres an employee in sheet1 cell(13,2) i want to copy sheet 2 columns b and c (rows 5 through 17) and insert them after column c.  if theres an employee in sheet 1 cell(14,2) i want to copy sheet 2 columns d and e (rows 5 through 17) and insert them after column e.  and so on until there are no more employees in cells(12,2) to cells (24,2).

Comment: You have two ws variables Possibly start your code out right.
   [code] Dim ws As Worksheet, sh As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets("Budget Output #2")
    Set sh = Sheets("Input")
[/code]

Comment: Um I do have two `ws` variables... `wsOut` and `wsIn` @Davesexcel

Answer (score 1):

I will let you figure out the answer.  Here is the correct structure:

```
For i ....  
    For j ...  
       with ws
       end with
    next j
next i
```

Answer (score -1):

You have two ws variables Possibly start your code out right.

```
  Dim ws As Worksheet, sh As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets("Budget Output #2")
    Set sh = Sheets("Input")
```